# USB Copy Protection

Tags: usb-flash-drive, disk-encryption

I am providing video and pdf content to my buyers/readers. And looking for some solution, where I can protect USB to get copied, means :

1. People should not be able to copy from USB (Copy/SaveAs)
2. People should not be able to write anything in USB
3. People should not be able to print .PDF files.
4. I can restrict one USB stick to work on Max. 2 computers

I find first 3 options with KAKASOFT USB PROTECTION TOOL but 4th option is not available with anyone. Can someone help?

Comment: I am thinking to make a BAT file (run on autorun), where once user plug with any computer, it grabs HDD serial number and put into any hidden file and check at every execution. Once there are more than 2 HDD serial number, it refuse to take another.

Comment: Obviously, if someone can _read_ a file, he can _copy_ it. Simply because copying is reading followed by writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a read-only USB drive is certainly possible. However, you wouldn’t be able to save usage information on it, then.

The video could be encrypted and only viewable with a custom program. However, implementing decryption where the key stays inaccessible is virtually impossible.

The PDF format already supports DRM.

You can rest assured, however, that every DRM scheme, online or offline, can and will be cracked unless you control the entire target computer, both hardware and software. Granted, this is unlawful in most countries, but that’s not going to help you.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Encrypted video will work for me. Would you please advise some program for that?

Comment: I don’t know if there’s any off-the-shelf software for that.